# Preview not matching with what I want

Tags: compositing-nodes

blender newbie here, I've been struggling trying to figure out why even tho I got the same nodes and connections the final result is different, I want the result on the right.

Edit: Added new picture after pressing f12 (to render)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the Compositor takes effect, you need to render the scene. Try to press <kbd>F12</kbd>. Also, it seems that you're using a different MatCap. Your render is most likely going to look different.

---

**Edit:** To change the selected MatCap, switch to the *Workbench* Render Engine (marked blue in the screenshot). This will cause the MatCap UI element to show up (marked red in the screenshot). If you click that element, a row of available MatCaps will show up. You just need to select the one that looks close to the reference.

[image: Steps]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already did it. How can I get the result of the right?

Comment: @Sergio I updated my answer with instructions on how to change the MatCap.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It really made a huge change setting that and twiking other settings in that section.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Sorry to bother again sr, I'm having a little trouble but with other scene, I checked the render engine and all the settings there, and they're the same but the final result looks different, i eidted the post with the other scenario.

Comment: The result I want is on the right

Comment: @Sergio I am sorry, but I can't tell what's missing. You have a sphere in your scene while the reference has a horse. Do you want your sphere to look white?

Comment: Yes! exactly, I want the sphere to look white like in the right image

Comment: Since you'll be using Eevee to render, replicating the render settings won't be enough to get the same look. You will need to give the objects the same material, and you will need to use the same lighting setup (environment light and direct lights). If you don't know how, let me know, and I will update my answer with more screenshots.

Comment: I played around with the materials and some settings and indeed, it was that, ¡you've helped a junior programmer implementing his first feature! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I am glad I was able to help.